# Laravel Parse error on @foreach

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, foreach, parse-error

I am following the video [Laravel 5.4 From Scratch: Eloquent Relationships and Comments](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/15) and have this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '['

I am getting it when I try to replicate the video and put:

```
@foreach ($film->comment as comment)

<p>{{$comment->body}}</p>

@endforeach
```

This is the section of code being highlighted on the error page:

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $film->comment; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as comment): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

However when I output just `{{$film->comments}}` it does give me a result:

`[{"id":1,"film_id":"1","body":"I loved this film!","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]`

I have a film table and comment table. In tinker it displays as I want e.g.

```
>>> $c = App\Comment::first();
=> App\Comment {#751
     id: "1",
     film_id: "1",
     body: "I loved this film!",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,    }
>>> $c->film;
=> App\Film {#746
     id: "1",
     title: "The Godfather",
     director: "Francis Ford Coppola",
     description: "It stars Marlon Brando and Al Pacino as the leaders of a fictional New York crime family. The story, spanning 1945 to 1955, chronicles the family under the patriarch Vito Corleone (Brando), focusing on the transformation of Michael Corleone (Pacino) from reluctant family outsider to ruthless mafia boss.",
     date: "1972-03-24",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,    }
```

Below are my models:

Comment Model:

```
class Comment extends Model

{
    public function film()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Film::class);
    }
}
```

Film Model:

```
class Film extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Try `@foreach ($film->comment as $comment)` notice the `$` on comment.

Comment: When I do that it says invalid argument

Comment: I think your doing a typo: loop over `$film->comments` not `$film->comment`, sorry i missed that initially.

Comment: Yes doing this worked: $film->comments as $film->comment
and the in paragraph $film->comment->body. Not sure why it wasnt like that in the vid? Thank you very much! You want to put answer so I can give you points :)

Comment: Maybe `@foreach($film->comments as $comment)`

Comment: Jeff foreach ($film->comments as $comment)
<p>{{$comment->body}}</p>
endforeach worked and is a bit neater Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach ($film->comments as $comment)
<p>{{$comment->body}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure $film->comments is not empty with adding

```
@if( count($film->comments) > 0 ) 
   @foreach($film->comments as $comment)
      <p>{{$comment->body}}</p>
   @endforeach
@endif
```